# How to add custom plugin on tinymce 4.9.2?

Tags: javascript, c#, tinymce, tinymce-4

There are tonns of examples where people call method `tinymce.PluginManager.add` but not a single full example where to call it. I managed to create a js file, in which I called this method and specified name of the plugin inside parameter for `tinymce.init` method. And it's called there. But I need to add the code to the same page where `tinymce.init` method is called. But it doesn't work neither before nor after `init` call. Here's what I'm trying just for the start:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('debugPlugin', function (editor, url) {
    console.log('debug');
});

tinymce.init(/*parameters here*/); //tried to switch those calls - didn't change anything
```

P.S. Separate js file won't work in my case, I need to put it in cshtml.

Comment: This is the normal process to inline the plugins and it seems to work fine here: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/QAhaab. Does that work for you? If so can you check and see if you're getting any console errors or similar in your local setup.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't understand that `tinymce.PluginManager.add` only registers plugin but you need to add it to `init` method parameters as well to work.